# How can I send message from eclipse to device

Tags: android, debugging, sms

I am working on an android app. I wrote a SMS app and i want to debug the app on my android device.
**The question is** : How can i send a message to my android device from eclipse.
I know how can I send a message to emulator from another emulator. I want to debug on device not emulator.

Thanks for your helps...

Comment: do you need to send an sms to your app installed on the phone or , what message are you talking about ?

Comment: i want to send a sms to my android device from eclipse. is it possible ??? for debugging app. ok

Comment: most likely not possible the way i think you want to do it.

Comment: You can only send sms `to your emulator` or `between emulators`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SMS is a mobile network operation. It needs another device to send SMS, you cannot use eclipse to send. But what you can do is, you can use another device connected to your pc ad use adb shell to send SMS

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es sms_body "SMS BODY GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Comment: I haven't got another device :( But when i found another device i will try. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It doesn't fix the principal question, not to spend money on debugging, but it's a good way to automatize some tests.

Answer (score 1):

If the device is rooted then you can modify the database of Messaging using you Application/Service. Once the DB is updated with proper values the messaging app will automatically display the DB

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You can send from another device to your testing device.

Answer (score -1):

You can send message from eclipse to your emulator

1) go to the ddms in eclipse

2) Select emulator control tab

3) In telephony Action write any number from which u want to send the message

4) write message and press send .

Comment: i know sending sms to emulator. I want to send sms to device which connects to PC with USB cable.

Comment: sorry but it is not possible to send message from eclipse to device .. but can you elaborate why you wanted to send message from eclipse to device?